# How do I get rid of the zero at the beginning of the output of the following code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for i in range(7,0,-1):
    for i in range(i-1):
        print i,
    print
```

The above code prints:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

I want to get rid of the zeroes in the first 4 lines.

Comment: `range(1,i-1)` is all

Comment: You know how to set the start/stop/increment of a `range()` on the 1st line, but then it's like you don't know how to set the start/stop on the second line...

Answer (score 2):

Start your range at 1 instead of the default 0:

```
for i in range(1, i-1):
    print i,
```

Instead of ranging to `i - 1`, adjust your outer loop to produce the right values but *increase* the end-point; there is little point in producing a range from 1 to 1 or from 1 to 0.

```
for i in range(6, 1, -1):
    for i in range(1, i):
        print i,
    print
```

This saves you from printing too many empty newlines at the end:

```
>>> for i in range(6, 1, -1):
...     for i in range(1, i):
...         print i,
...     print
... 
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2
1
```

You could also use `print i + 1` instead of starting at 1; decrement the values in the outer loop in that case:

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    for i in range(i):
        print i + 1,
    print
```